# 403 Forbidden when accessing code.google.com

Tags: google-code, docker, digital-ocean

When installing docker via "go get", I am getting 403 forbidden. The IP I am accessing from is in the ny1 datacenter.

[code]

```
ops@sally:~/gocode/src/github.com/dotcloud/docker$ curl -v https://code.google.com/p/go/source/checkout
* About to connect() to code.google.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 74.125.21.138...
* Connected to code.google.com (74.125.21.138) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA
* Server certificate:
*    subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Mountain View; O=Google Inc; CN=*.google.com
*    start date: 2013-12-11 12:34:50 GMT
*    expire date: 2014-04-10 00:00:00 GMT
*    subjectAltName: code.google.com matched
*    issuer: C=US; O=Google Inc; CN=Google Internet Authority G2
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /p/go/source/checkout HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: code.google.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Content-Length: 934
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Date: Fri, 17 Jan 2014 22:03:23 GMT
< Server: GFE/2.0
< Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
<
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 403 (Request not allowed from your country)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><img src=//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm.gif alt=Google></a>
  <p><b>403.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>Request not allowed from your country  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
* Connection #0 to host code.google.com left intact
```

[/code]

Answer (score 0):

IPO There is nothing you can do except contacting Google support and giving them your IP.

Temporary you can use an IP changer tool e.g. TOR, ...